# Store subquery results to be reused throughout query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to re-use the results of a sub-query so I don't have to keep calling it through out my code, I tried:

```
WITH MAX_VERSIONS AS (
    SELECT MAX(vernum) AS VERNUM, MAX(defvern) AS DEFVERN
    FROM   llattrdata, DTREE DT 
    WHERE  id = dt.dataid 
            AND defid = 3070056 
            AND attrid = 4
) 
SELECT ID
FROM   llattrdata ad, DTREE DT 
WHERE  ad.id = dt.dataid 
        AND ad.defid = 3070056 
        AND ad.attrid = 4
        AND ad.VERNUM = MAXVERSIONS.VERNUM
        AND ad.DEFVERN = MAXVERSIONS.DEFVERN;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CROSS JOIN` since it only returns single row:

```
;WITH MAX_VERSIONS AS 
(
    SELECT MAX(vernum) AS VERNUM, MIN(defvern) AS DEFVERN
    FROM    llattrdata
            INNER JOIN DTREE DT
                ON id = dt.dataid 
    WHERE   defid = 3070056 
            AND attrid = 4
) 
SELECT  ID
FROM    llattrdata ad
        INNER JOIN DTREE DT 
            ON ad.id = dt.dataid 
        CROSS JOIN MAX_VERSIONS mv
WHERE   defid = 3070056 
        AND attrid = 4
        AND DT.VERNUM = mv.VERNUM    -- must also define which table the column
        AND DT.DEFVERN = mv.DEFVERN; -- is coming from to avoid ambiguity
                                     -- not sure whether it is from [ad] or [DT]
```

As an alternative, if you wanted to reuse the value over and over again without using a CTE, you can declare and store the value inside a variable:

```
DECLARE
    MAX_VERNUM NUMBER(10);
    MAX_DEFVERN  NUMBER(10);

SELECT  MAX(vernum), MIN(defvern)
        INTO MAX_VERNUM, MAX_DEFVERN
FROM    llattrdata
        INNER JOIN DTREE DT
            ON id = dt.dataid 
WHERE   defid = 3070056 
        AND attrid = 4

SELECT  ID
FROM    llattrdata ad
        INNER JOIN DTREE DT 
            ON ad.id = dt.dataid 
WHERE   defid = 3070056 
        AND attrid = 4
        AND VERNUM = MAX_VERNUM
        AND DEFVERN = MAX_DEFVERN;
```

Comment: I'm getting that `mv` is disconnected

Comment: That's what I figured but Oracle is saying that 'mv is disconnected from the rest of the join graph'. Then when I run it I get `"column ambiguously defined"`

Comment: @Batman you should also specify to where VERNUM and DEFVERN coming from. Like `...DT.VERNUM = mv.VERNUM
        AND DT.DEFVERN = mv.DEFVERN;` I'm not really sure which table but that is just an example.

Comment: That did it. I'm wondering what would be an alternative to using `WITH` say. I wanted to just store these two values `Max(vernum/defvern)` so I could reuse them in multiple queries part of the same script?

Comment: I have updated the user by using a variable instead of a CTE.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you go through all this trouble when you can use window functions:

```
SELECT ID
FROM (SELECT ID,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY defid, attrid, ORDER BY versum, defvern DESC) as seqnum
      FROM llattrdata ad JOIN
           DTREE DT 
           ON ad.id = dt.dataid 
      WHERE ad.defid = 3070056 
     ) ad
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Window functions should have better performance than a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I'm sorry, not entirely sure how this stores `MAX(vernum), MAX(defvern)` for reuse

Comment: @Batman . . . It doesn't.  It accomplishes what you presumably intend with your query, in a more efficient and concise method.

Comment: Okay but is it still efficient if I have to do it 6 times for 1 report?

Comment: @Batman . . . This should be more efficient than a `join` and `group by`.  I don't know why you would be doing this multiple times for a report.

Comment: The report I'm looking at does this multiple times because they want to use the two max values returned as parameters for other queries. So what they've done is everytime they need those params, they make that call. Which is why I'm looking for a way to get those values only once, and reuse them.